# What is the varṇa (class) of Actors or Actresses?

Tags: smriti

Actors or Actresses are usually found to poke their unscrupulous nose into the matters they lack substantial understanding of, mere to perpetuate their celebrity status whilst having negligible consideration of the welfare of society. As it is said,

> He who plunges into action without considering the problem, thinking that he is reforming the world—it is he who is creating greater confusion and misery.

Looking at their occupations & role in corrupting the society, it seems Smṛitī would rather check their privileges otherwise they enjoy it in the modern Kali world. So, I was wondering what's their varṇa according to the scriptures, if at all they have?

Comment: where is that quote taken from? JK?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes. Though it's contextual, I don't imply to suggest JK an authority into Hindu matters.

Comment: Smritis talk about birth based varnas. All actors are not required to have the same varna. Two famous Bengali actors -- [Uttam Kumar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttam_Kumar) and [Soumitra Chaterjee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soumitra_Chatterjee) -- were for example both Brahmins.

Comment: @Rickross In other words, acting occupation belongs to which Varṇa?

Comment: Does not belong to any of the 4 @Mr.Sigma.

Comment: Yes. You can answer whatever it is. @Rickross

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acting is not an occupation that is recommended for any of the Varnas. Not even recommended for any of the mixed castes.

> Manu Smriti 10.80. Among the several occupations the most commendable
> are, teaching the Veda for a Brahmana, protecting (the people) for a
> Kshatriya, and trade for a Vaisya.

Similarly from the Parashara Smriti's Chapter 1:

> 61. A king of the Kshatriya caste should arm himself,and have his troops ; should protect his people ; should overcome the forces of a
>     hostile king ; and rule the State in the way prescribed by law.
> 62. To invest money on interest, to be a jeweller, to tend cattle, tillage and trade, — these are declared as occupations for the Vaisya
>     caste,
> 63. The highest virtue for a Shoodra is to serve the members of the regenerate castes. Fruitless for him is everything else that he may
>     do.

So, we can't say what is THE Varna of anyone who by profession is an actor.

Actors are always condemned as degraded in the Smritis. So, acting hasn't been recommended as a suitable occupation for any Varna.

> Manu Smriti 4.214. Nor the food (given) by an informer, by one who
> habitually tells falsehoods, or by one who sells (the rewards for)
> sacrifices, nor the food (given) by an actor, a tailor, or an
> ungrateful (man),
>
> 8.102. Brahmanas who tend cattle, who trade, who are mechanics, actors (or singers), menial servants or usurers, the (judge) shall treat like
> Sudras.

The following verse is quoted by Madhava while commenting on one verse of the Parashara Smriti. It regards actor to be one of the lowest castes.

> Washerman, cobbler, actor, Varuda, Kaivarta, Meda and Bhilla, these
> seven are described in the Smriti as lowcastes. (3)
>
> *Angiras Smriti, Chapter 1.*

Comment: "8.102. Brahmanas who tend cattle, who trade, who are mechanics, actors (or singers), menial servants or usurers, the (judge) shall treat like Sudras." answers to an extent. Thanks.

Comment: but world inverted every one follows actor whatever he does is virtue, the lowest of tribe is given so much importance all immoral things also people think them as virtue because the actor did so with his families like remarrying daughter with kids or supporting livin relationship